# Script to batch convert sound files

Tags: bash

As Sound Converter now hangs for me in Xenial (since a few days), I wanted to write a bash script to simulate it:

I want to convert a few *.wav files in a directory specified by the variable wav_path to 'equivalent' mp3 files in an existing directory specified by mp3_path. I've got the following so far, though it's incorrect:

```
for i in "$wav_path"/*.wav;
do
    lame -h -b 192 "$i" "${i%.wav}.mp3"
done
```

What should I change this to?

Comment: You should explain in what way it is incorrect - what do you want it to do? what actually happens?

Comment: I've moved on a little. I'm now having problem with:

Comment: I've moved on a little. I'm now having problem with:
for i in "$wav_path"/*.wav;
do
    basename "$i" .wav
    lame -h -b 192 "$i" "$mp3_path/filename.mp3"
done
It should convert all .wav files in directory wav_path and put them as .mp3 files in directory mp3_path. It actually does e.g. Encoding wav/Track 14.wav to mp3/filename.mp3.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with this new information - including the definitions of `wav_path` and `mp3_path` which appear to be missing from the code you posted.

Comment: It's difficult to edit questions with much info as there is a low limit on the amount of comment allowed in a message. It would help if this site allowed attached files. However, I shall try.

Comment: wav_path="$1"
mp3_path="$2"

Comment: wav_path="$1"
mp3_path="$2"

Comment: wav_path="$1"
mp3_path="$2"
for i in "$wav_path"/*.wav;
do
    filename=${i%.wav}
    lame -h -b 192 "$i" "$mp3_path"/"$filename".mp3
done
This gives for each file:
Can't init outfile 'mp3/wav/Track 1.mp3'

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working. Relevant code is:

```
for i in "$wav_path"/*.wav;
do
    filename="${i##*/}"
    filename="${filename%.*}"
    lame -h -b 192 "$i" "$mp3_path"/"$filename".mp3
done
```